# Replace multiple IPs in multiple files with sed HP-UX

Tags: replace, sed, ip

Can anyone tell me how can i mass replace IPs in multiple files by 1 command? what does this sed command does?

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/x.x.x.x/g' *
```

Really need help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sed does:

```
s/pattern1/pattern2/g
```

Replaces `pattern1` with `pattern2`

`[0-9]\{1,3\}` =  `1 to 3` digits from `0-9`
`\.` means a single dot `.`

So in theory this should change all IP in all files to given IP `x.x.x.x`
`*` mean all files in this folder
So no original IP are left, so be careful with this.

PS this is not 100% working. Example this number `3452.343.13.34` (not IP) will be change to `3x.x.x.x`

Comment: It actually doesn't seem to work. I do want to replace all the IPs in all files in the folder. The IP remains in tact actually and when i do a grep for x.x.x.x i get nothing.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Show us your input. With my files it works, and so does this: `echo "test 10.5.2.20 and another 192.168.12.23" | sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/x.x.x.x/g'
test x.x.x.x and another x.x.x.x`

Comment: sorry for the late reply, was busy with other stuff. Anyway there is no output. It just 'hangs'. 

BTW can it but run in Solaris10 or 11 as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/\([12]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\.\)\{3\}[12]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]/x.x.x.x/g"
```

but

1. If a number (digit) is before or after, it is ignored and consider internal part as IP
2. If number bigger than 255 and lower of 300 appear, they are still consider as IP
3. IP using a start with 0 are not include (like 120.008.099.234)

If those think count, a more complexe sed is to be build (cascade one I think) like

```
sed "s/.*/#&#/;s/\([^0-9.]\)\([012]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\.\)\{3\}[12]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\([^0-9.]\)/\1x.x.x.x\3/g;s/^#\(.*\)#$/\1/"
```

(still possible number between 255 and 300)

Comment: This kind of makes more sense, however like the earlier method, it does not work too.

# sed "s/.*/#&#/;s/\([^0-9.]\)\([012]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\.\)\{3\}[12]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]\([^0-9.]\)/\1x.x.x.x\3/g;s/^#\(.*\)#$/\1/" /etc/hosts

#
# Internet host table
#
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.130.128 unknown # Added by DHCP


Btw I ran this on Solaris 10.

Comment: just testest on our aix ont /etc/host and it work. so maybe a sed option to set (like the --posix in GNU version). I alos simplyfy the "[0-9]\{0,1\}[0-9]" by "[0-9]\{1,2\}" (twice in command).